# Substitute variable name in a dynamic json property

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I would like to use the variable `settingName` for the dynamic json property. How can i accomplish that?

```
let settingName = 'LaunchNext';

DSEvents
| where  Timestamp > ago(1d) and Data contains (settingName)
| summarize count() by tostring(parsejson(tostring(Data.Settings)).LaunchNext.value)
```

I want to substitute the variable instead of the actual property

> parsejson(tostring(Data.Settings)).***LaunchNext***.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclosing the variable in `[]` worked for me

```
tostring(parsejson(tostring(Data.Settings)).[settingName].value)
```